# append 0's to dataframe string column if not specific length

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column `object`.

How do I append "0" at the end of strings which are of length 4.

```
Column
12356
1287
23868
5643
45634
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`str.ljust`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.ljust.html#pandas.Series.str.ljust) whick takes as first argument the `width` that the string should be and the character to be filled with (on right side of string) if the width is less than the specified:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.ljust(width=5, fillchar='0')

print(df)

     col
0  12356
1  12870
2  23868
3  56430
4  45634
```

Data setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'col':'12356 1287 23868 5643 45634'.split()}
                  ,dtype=('object'))

     col
0  12356
1   1287
2  23868
3   5643
4  45634
```

Answer (score 1):

One more method can be done using list comprehension

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'col': '12356 1287 23868 5643 45634'.split()}
    , dtype=('object'))

df['col'] = [i + '0' if len(i) == 4 else i for i in df['col']]
```

output `col`:

```
     col
0  12356
1  12870
2  23868
3  56430
4  45634
```